# Issue in date difference in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to subtract Mar 11, 2016 from Mar 14, 2016 in javascript like this: 
date1.parseDate() - date2.parseDate()/1000/60/60/24.
I should get a difference of 3 days. However, I am getting 2.95833 because of a change in the daylight savings time. I am thinking of using the round function to fix this. Is there any other better way to handle this?

Comment: You should use a library rather than doing naive arithmetic.

Comment: @ssube what if this is the only thing OP uses a date for? Would it be worth downloading a whole library for just this?

Comment: @putvande: yes, it would. otherwise you get this exact issue, over and over and over and over, and it'll be nearly impossible to debug,  because usually by the time you get to it, the cause (DST switchover) is gone

Comment: @putvande that's why we have optimizing minifiers: you can bundle the library and drop unused parts. Considering how many gotchas there are in timezone/DST handling, it's almost always worth using a date library.

Comment: yes the only better way of doing this would be to use moment.js & moment timezone